# Modifying the number of default chunks in the Page Module for PyroCMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I want to have 2 default chunks instead of 1 when making a new page.

The reason is, my main template is split into 2 sections and I want to start with 2 chunks.

What I would like to do is edit the page module so that whenever a user creates a new page they will always start with 2 chunks that I have named and defined.

What would I have to modify in order to achieve this?

Note: I already modified the page module and database to add some custom fields. I assume this is the same deal but I can't find where the initial chunk is being created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nick-pyett. Here is the code that worked for me.

this is the final code:

```
$page->chunks = array(array(
'id' => 'NEW',
'slug' => 'default',
'class' => '',
'body' => '',
'type' => 'wysiwyg-advanced',
),
array(
'id' => 'NEW2',
'slug' => 'default2',
'class' => '',
'body' => '',
'type' => 'wysiwyg-advanced',
),
);
```

I looked to see where the id ends up. It seems to get appended to the name of each element. Like so:

> chunk_slug[NEW2]

The actual slug goes into the first input on the chunk which would be the slug you would use to call it in a page.

> {{ pages:chunk id="{{ page:id }}" name="default2" }}

Answer (score 2):

If you look at around line 340 in the admin controller of the pages module, there is an array being created in the `$pages->chunks` property. I amended this as below by adding another array/object and this creates pages with two chunks called "default" and "default2".

```
$page->chunks = array((object) array(
    'id' => 'NEW',
    'slug' => 'default',
    'body' => '',
    'type' => 'wysiwyg-advanced',
),
(object) array(
        'id' => 'NEW2',
        'slug' => 'default2',
        'body' => '',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg-advanced',
    ),
);
```

To be honest I'm not sure what the id does, but probably be best to make sure it is unique.